# Passing an array in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have 4 methods
In Class A

```
-(void)Method1
{

}
```

In Class B

```
-(void)Method2
{  
     //calling method3 here  
}  
-(void)Method3
{  
  //calling method4 here    
}  
-(NsMutablearray*)Method4
{  
  return array;  
}
```

I am calling method2 from method1, and it goes upto method4 and method4 returns an nsmutablearray. How can i get that array in my method1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few ways to accomplish this task :

First :Need to change your method signature, and use as :

```
-(void)method1{ 
  ClassB *classBObj=[ClassB new];
   NSMutableArray *tempArray = [classBObj method2]; 
}
```

In ClassB

```
-(NSMutableArray *)method2{  
    return [self method3];  
}  
-(NSMutableArray *)method3{  
  return [self method4]; 
}  
-(NSMutableArray *)method4{  
  ...
  return array;  
}
```

Second : If you want same array as in method4 in method1 without any modifications, post a notification, and observe it in ClassA.

Third: You can use delegate for this, as this is 1-to-1, this will be better than notification.

Fourth: If you dont want to change your method signature create a shared class having a property of type NSArray and use that property to pass your arrays within the methods and classes.

Comment: actually my problem is method3 is delegate method  - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request how can change return type here according to you

Comment: if it is a delegate...then you have other 3 ways... as you can see I mentioned 4 ways.

Answer (score 2):

Change your methods like:

```
-(void)Method1
{ 
   NSMutableArray *tempArray = [classbObj method2]; 
}
```

In Class B

```
-(NSMutablearray *)Method2
{  
    return [self method3];  
}  
-(NSMutablearray *)Method3
{  
  return [self method4]; 
}  
-(NSMutablearray*)Method4
{  
  return array;  
}
```

Comment: Here method 3 is delegate of method 2 so i coudnt do it - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request this is method3 i mention

Answer (score 1):

You have call method 2 like this. In method4Ary you will have returned value

```
NSMutableArray * method4Ary = [method1_obj Method2]
```

Comment: Notice that Method2 has a return type of `void` so this won't work.

Comment: You can have return type of NSMutablearray

Comment: @vishnu you can change your method like Midhun answer

Answer (score 1):

Use **delegate** for backward messaging in class.

Refer [Basic Delegate Example](http://coderchrismills.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/basic-delegate-example/) link for more reference.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the return type from **`void`** to **`NsMutablearray`**